# .rtf file data is not rendering in a Jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I created a .rtf file with below content with border.

```
cell 1  lots of text in cell two    cell 3
```

When I exported rtf file into jasper report using Markup as rtf, I got only text (below data)

```
cell 1lots of text in cell twocell 3
```

I am using TIBCO Jaspersoft Studio-6.1.1.final version jasper.

Below I am adding JRXML file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.1.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.1  -->
<!-- 2015-11-16T12:10:05 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Test_RTF" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="e4e612e9-7787-4540-a6b9-b2d362a29f32">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.sql.tables" value=""/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="Sample DB"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select '{\rtf1\ansi\deff0
\trowd
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx1000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx2000
\clbrdrt\brdrs\clbrdrl\brdrs\clbrdrb\brdrs\clbrdrr\brdrs
\cellx3000
cell 1\intbl\cell
lots of text in cell two\intbl\cell
cell 3\intbl\cell
\row
}' rtf_simple from dual]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="RTF_SIMPLE" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField isStretchWithOverflow="true" isBlankWhenNull="true">
                <reportElement x="110" y="30" width="410" height="30" uuid="43e8a2fb-5db5-4290-8db7-51c93c330f22"/>
                <textElement markup="rtf"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{RTF_SIMPLE}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Here I added rtf text code into select statement using dual. If I am adding same text into rtf file.

I am getting text with border, but when I am adding it into jasper report I am getting text only.

[update]

This is a simplified use-case. Our actual requirement is , we have .rtf documents stored in DB as blob. We want to insert content of these documents in between our big report. these rtf files contain Text, tables and images. When I am trying to read this rtf file, then only text is coming. Can someone please suggest any other alternative to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a feeling that it is similar to `markup="html"` you should not expect jasper report to be able to format tables, images eccecc

`<span style='border:5px solid red;color:red'>Test</span>`

with `markup="html"`  will only display a red text "Test", hence **no** red border

The **textfield displays text** (formatted text) so the markup (html and rtf) is for formatting the text (bold, italic, font, size,color) ecc.

Unfortunately, you need the `box` command to add border to your field es.

```
<box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
  <topPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
  <leftPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
  <bottomPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
  <rightPen lineWidth="0.25"/>
</box>
```

Comment: This is a simplified usecase. Our actual requirement is , we have .rtf document stored in DB as blob. We want to insert content of this document in between our big report. these rtf file contain Text, tables , images. When I am tring to read this rtf file only text is coming. Can you please suggest any other alternative to achieve this.

Comment: Surely you can not pass it as is into jasper report, (images, tables ecc. will not be supported). The only idea that I can get is to parse the rtf with something like, rtfparserkit then handle the different objects, tables, immagies ecc and if you like to ouput with jasper report maybe move towards DynamicJasper

Comment: So parse it, use DynamicJasper to create a report representing it and include this report in your main.... it is not easy.... booh, sorry no other ideas...

Comment: Another way would be that you develop your own component in jasper report. the rtf component....

Comment: How I can create my own rtf component in jasper report ? Any idea or hits or link.So that I will try this option...

Comment: Start with this: http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/introduction-custom-components-ireport-designer

Comment: There nothing mention exactly. Is there any other solution for this ?

Comment: The only other thing that I can come up with is in java convert the rtf to html --> http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/136483/Java-How-to-convert-RTF-into-HTML, then use the html component in jasper to render an image.... or find some library that can render an image of your rtf and pass this to jasper...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. but when I converted rtf to image, graphical components are not comming. like if there is a table , then only text is coming like this..How I can get the graphical content also ?

Comment: I don't konw you need to search the web or ask another question

Comment: Thank you very much Petter. I will check this.

Comment: AdvancedRTFEditorKit maybe can render you content correctly... the cerate the image form it...